# What are the changes in solr 8.2 for querying block join?

Tags: solr

I trying to understand how block join works in solr.
I followed http://yonik.com/solr-nested-objects/ and i am able to fetch child documents with parent document in solr 7.4 but in solr 8.2 it does not fetch child documents with parent document.
basically anything in fl=*,[child] where anything in [] does not take affect in query.
Can anyone share knowledge that what is the change in solr 8?

Solr 7.4 returns below data.

```
q=cat_s:(fantasy OR sci-fi)&
fl=id,[child parentFilter=type_s:book]'
  "response":{"numFound":2,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"book1",
        "_childDocuments_":[
        {
          "id":"book1_c1",
          "type_s":"review",
          "review_dt":"2015-01-03T14:30:00Z",
          "stars_i":5,
          "author_s":"yonik",
          "comment_t":["A great start to what looks like an epic series!"]},
        {
          "id":"book1_c2",
          "type_s":"review",
[...]
```

Solr 8.2 returns only parent document

```
q=cat_s:(fantasy OR sci-fi)&
fl=id,[child parentFilter=type_s:book]'
  "response":{"numFound":2,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"book1",
       }
}
```

Comment: Did you reindex after upgrading, or are you working with the same index files?

Comment: I am following http://yonik.com/solr-nested-objects/, i tried in 8.2 and i could not retrieve document as mentioned in tutorial but when i tried in 7.4 it worked as it is mentioned in tutorial.